# Find class in complex structure through jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

HTML structure is

```
<div class="menu_item cf">
    <div class="menu_desc">
        <h4><a href="#">Garlic Bread Sticks</a></h4>
        <p>Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare.</p>

        <div class="social_links cf">
            <a href="#" class="fb">facebook</a>
            <a href="#" class="tw">twitter</a>
        </div>

        <div class="menu_links">
            <a class="btn_yellow">detail</a>
            <a class="green_btn_right_arrow order_btn">order</a>
            <p class="item_price">AED 18</p>
        </div><!-- menu_links -->
    </div><!-- menu_desc -->

    <div class="img_cont">
        <a href="#"><img src="images/menu_item_img1.png" alt=""></a>
    </div><!-- img_cont -->

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="order_cont cf">
        <img src="images/order_arrow_up.png" alt="" class="menu_order_arrow" />
        <form method="post" action="" name="">
            <label>
                <span>Quantity</span><br>
                <input type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" />
            </label>

            <div class="float-l">
                <span>Quantity</span><br>
                <div class="selc_cont">
                    <select>
                        <option>Small</option>
                        <option>Large</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <a href="#" class="black_btn_right_arrow">Add to Cart</a>
        </form>
    </div><!-- order_cont -->
</div><!-- menu_item -->
```

What I want is to find first `div` with class name `order_cont` when clicking on class `order_btn` button. As it will be listing, so I want only first div with class name `order_cont`.

What I tried is

```
$('.order_btn').nextAll('.order_cont:first');
```

Also

```
$('.order_btn').dblclick(function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.order_cont').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

But no luck. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: $('.order_cont').slice(0,1)

Comment: @Cthulhu: You have something against `.first()`? But the OP doesn't really want the first in the document, I'm 99% certain the OP wants the first one *after* the "button" that was double-clicked.

Comment: Well, he just said first... And yes, `.first()` is okay, I just forgot about it somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nextAll` didn't work because the div isn't a sibling of the "button."

You need to go up to the sibling first. Unless the HTML indentation is misleading, it looks like `menu_desc` is the relevant sibling, so:

```
$(".order_btn").on("relevant-event", function() {
    $(this).closest(".menu_desc").nextAll(".order_cont").first().slideToggle('fast');
});
```

(If the relevant event is `dblclick`, then replace `relevant-event` with `dblclick` above.)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(this).closest('.menu_item').find('.order_cont').slideToggle('fast');
```